# H.264 to MPEG2 conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I have videos which code and format is h.264. I need to transform this videos to mpeg2 format (the same codec: h.264). Everything I try doesn't work... Any idea? I think it can be done with ffmpeg.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

MPEG-1 system format (`-f mpeg` option, `.mpg` file extension) does not support h.264 video streams. There are MPEG-2 Transport Stream (`-f mpegts`) and MPEG-2 Program Stream (PS) (e.g `-f dvd` and `-f vob`) container formats that do. The conversion command will look like the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -vcodec copy -f vob output_video.vob
```

Run `ffmpeg -formats` for a list of supported container formats. See also [Comparison of container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats).